# MVC4 + Bootstrap + DataTables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I created a new MVC 4 web project (VS 2012 Express) and installed the Twitter Bootstrap package:

PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4

Seems to be ok, but I needed to add DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/) but can't seem to get it to work.

I edited the _BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml file to include the datatables js:

```
<link href="@Styles.Url("~/Content/css-responsive")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
    @Html.Partial("_html5shiv")
```

in my View i have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            } );
        </script>
```

and set the ID of the Table to "example"

It doesn't seem to be working though... the view was autogenerated by Visual Studio so i have also added the  tags to the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a problem with including the JS files.

_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml had:

```
     @Scripts.Render("~/js")
```

when it should have been

```
     @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts")
```

This solved the problem.